# CMS homepage content not changed

Tags: cms-pages, magento2.3.4, home-page

I am new to Magento.

I have setup the Magento 2.3.4.

I am seeing below homepage:

[image]

To change the message **CMS homepage content goes here.**, I have made changes in cms_page table like below:

[image]

Restarted *Apache* and *MySQL* from **XAMPP**.

But still not able to see new message on the page.

What am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush the FPC cache in order to see the new changes.

Please go to the webroot directory and run the following command:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Or

Navigate to Admin Panel > System > Cache Management and click on Flush Magento Cache

Reference doc: https://meetanshi.com/blog/clear-magento-2-cache/